# ReferenceError and the global object

Tags: javascript, window, referenceerror, global-object

In JavaScript in the browser `window` is the global object, which means every variable defined in the global scope is a child of `window`. So why do I get this result:

```js
console.log(window.foo); // No error, logs "undefined".
console.log(foo);        // Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined.
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYsh6/)

Those two lines should be the same, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because with `window.foo` you are explicitly looking for `foo` property of `window` object which is not the case in latter option. In the latter option, if `foo` isn't defined, you should as developer be able to know that it isn't defined and get the clear error warning rather than interpreter setting it to `undefined` on its own (like first case) which will lead to *unexpected* results.

**[Reference Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError):**

> Represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.
>   A ReferenceError is thrown when trying to dereference a variable that has not been declared.

Take a look at this article for more info:

- [Understanding JavaScript’s ‘undefined’](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/)

Quoting from above article:

> A Reference is considered unresolvable **if its base value is undefined**. Therefore a property reference is unresolvable if the value before the dot is undefined. The following example would throw a ReferenceError but it doesn’t because TypeError gets there first. This is because the base value of a property is subject to CheckObjectCoercible (ECMA 5 9.10 via 11.2.1) which throws a TypeError when trying to convert Undefined type to an Object.

**Examples:**

```
var foo;
foo.bar; //TypeError (base value, foo, is undefined)
bar.baz; //ReferenceError (bar is unersolvable)
undefined.foo; //TypeError (base value is undefined)
```

**References which are neither properties or variables are by definition unresolvable and will throw a ReferenceError, So:**

```
foo; //ReferenceError
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first example (window.foo) you are accessing a property of the window object. JavaScript returns "undefined" for when you are trying to access a non existent property of a object. It's designed that way.

In the second example you are referencing a variable directly, and since it does not exists an error is raised.

It's just the way JavaScript is designed and works.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can assign object fields on the fly like that, so `window.foo` is *nearly (see comments below)* equivalent to `var foo;` *when defined in the global context,* whereas just calling `foo` out of the blue makes the browser panic 'cause it down't even know which object to look in. Notice, if you do:

```
//when in global context, 'var' sets a property on the window object
var foo;

console.log(foo);
//it will then also log `undefined` instead of throwing the error.

//if you then do:
foo = "abbazabba";

console.log(window.foo);
// it will return "abbazabba"
```

Comment: `window.foo` is not equivalent to `var foo`.

Comment: @TimDown. can you elaborate some more please? maybe in an answer?

Comment: @TimDown & @gdoron Okay, that is a bit untrue - what I meant was window.foo is equivalent to `var foo` when declared in the global context.

Comment: It's still not quite equivalent. For example, it's possible to delete a property of the global object that has been explicitly set (after `window.foo = "bar";`, `delete window.foo;` deletes the `foo` property and returns `true`) whereas it's not possible to delete a variable (after `var foo = "bar";`, `delete window.foo;` does nothing and returns `false`).

Comment: @TimDown Maybe not in your browser, but in mine, `var foo = "bar"; delete window.foo;` returns `true` (as does `window.foo = "bar"; delete foo;`) `foo` then throws the error, and `window.foo` returns undefined. In fact, `var foo; (window.foo === foo)` also returns true! They seem pretty dang equivalent to me. (Granted, again, only in the global scope.)

Comment: I guess you're trying it in the console, which changes things because the console uses `eval()` and code executed with `eval()` behaves slightly differently from code executed normally. Try it in a test page instead.

Comment: @TimDown haha, you should have quit when I accepted defeat, son! your Fiddle shows them as the same! I modified it, though, to show the difference (and prove _my own damn self_ wrong.): http://jsfiddle.net/jking/SZq2R/2/

Comment: Ahhh, it needs to be in the global scope, of course. Changing the jsFiddle mode to "no wrap (body)" fixes it. http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/SZq2R/

Comment: @TimDown I believe(d) you, bro! You totally win! It's okay, you can rest easy tonight.

Comment: @TimDown Hey, man - at least you _did_ succeed at making the point! And a good time was had while it lasted. No apologies necessary, though, I (honestly) am grateful that you taught me that. Thanks!