# undefined, how you work?

Tags: javascript, undefined, referenceerror

Just a simple question :)

if I have :

```
var user = {'name': 'Fred'};
```

So

```
console.log(user.name); // Fred
console.log(user.age); // undefined
```

But

```
console.log(test); // ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

I don't understand why because for me it's the same as

```
console.log(window.test); // undefined
```

In my project, i try to check if a global variable exist but I have a referenceError... I don't really understand why the followinf code doesn't work...

```
if (TestGlobal) // ReferenceError: TestGlobal is not defined
   console.log(' allo 1 ');

if (typeof(TestGlobal ) !== 'undefined') // Ok
   console.log(' allo 1 ');
```

Comment: Note that referencing a variable `test` as a property of `window` will work _only_ if `test` is a global variable.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102862/referenceerror-and-the-global-object

Comment: Sorry for the double question and thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…and a simple answer:

- Property references always evaluate to their value or the `undefined` value if the key does not exist, as long as the base value is not undefined (then a TypeError would be thrown).
- Variables throw ReferenceErrors if not defined before, unless they are used with the  [`typeof` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (where they just evaluate to `"undefined"`).