# why alert(foo) foo outputs error while window.foo is undefined?

Tags: javascript, windows, variables, global-variables

```
alert(foo) //ReferenceError: foo is not defined
alert(window.foo) //undefined
```

Because of `foo === window.foo`, I think `alert(foo)` should have the same behavior as `window.foo`.

what's the difference between `foo` and  `window.foo` ?

what happened when `alert(foo)` ?

tks

Comment: you need to define variables before you use them or else it will throw. you can check any old object, including window, for any old property, and if it's nothing that the result is undefined instead of error.

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102862/referenceerror-and-the-global-object). 

keywork: Reference Error