# "x=x || 4" generates `ReferenceError: x is not defined` error

Tags: javascript

Why does `x = x || 4` or even `x=(x||5)` generate `ReferenceError: x is not defined` error, but `var x=x || 4` work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

This is because variable declarations are processed first (hoisting). The [MDN page on `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) explains it well:

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This
>   behaviour is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable
>   declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

So the following would also work:

```js
x = x || 4;
var x;
```

Comment: So, why does `x=(x||5)` generate error? Additionally, I don't want use `var` , the variable should be declared globally.

Comment: Because variable `x` is not known to the parser - and an attempt to access its value throws `ReferenceError`. If you really want to go with global variables, use `window.x = window.x || 4` syntax.

Comment: Note that `x = window.x || 4` will work fine in non-strict mode, but in the strict mode throws an error.

Comment: Yep @raina77ow is spot on. But using globals like that is something to be avoided if possible.

Comment: `x=5` does not generate error so why does `x = x||3` generate error, while in both statements `x` is not declared in advance. Indeed Also, for me `x = x||3` and `x = window.x||3` seems equivalent.

Comment: Strict mode won't allow either. In non-strict mode, you can get away with `x = 5` since you are defining `x`. But the second statement requires `x` to be already defined, since you are using its value.

Comment: And have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10102862/645956) for why `window.x` works.

Answer (score -1):

You're attempting to use a variable that hasn't been declared before. This results in a Reference Error.

[edit]
so many wrong words.

[exit] @grc got it right.

Comment: `x = x` is assignment operation, not comparison

Answer (score -1):

`x = x || 4` means assigning x or 4 in variable x. 
if x is null 4 is assigned to variable `x`.

May be you have not declare `x` variable. that's why you are getting `x is not defined`

If you try below it work :

```
var x;
x=x||4;
alert(x);
```

This will also work :

```
x=x||4;
var x;
alert(x);
```