# Why does accessing a non-existent object property result in `undefined` instead of throwing a `ReferenceError`?

Tags: javascript, variables, object-properties

When I try to use an undeclared variable I get `ReferenceError`:

```js
console.log(a); // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

I could use a variable first and define it later and it won’t be a problem due to hoisting.

```js
console.log(a); // undefined

var a;
```

But when I declare an object why would the execution context let me use any property of it?

```js
var obj = {};

console.log(obj.a); // undefined
console.log(obj.why); // undefined
```

Why are these allowed even though `a` and `why` are never declared anywhere?

Comment: Not exactly a *duplicate*, but a good explanation on the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102862/referenceerror-and-the-global-object

Comment: Related (about the difference between variables and properties): [var vs this in Javascript object](/q/4946625/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language design has specified that trying to access a non existent property on an object will simply return `undefined`.

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.a);   // undefined
```

But, that trying to access a variable that is not defined anywhere within the current or parent scopes is a ReferenceError.

```
console.log(b);       // ReferenceError
```

> Why are these allowed even though a and why are never declared
>   anywhere?

It's just the way the language is designed.  I can see some reasons for it to be this way, but the real reason that it was decided to make it this way is only in the heads of some of the original designers.  Our job at this point is to understand how it works and write code that is compatible with the current design (since we can't change the current language design).

---

There are ways to work-around this issue by testing for these undefined variables such as:

```
if (typeof b === "undefined")
```

Or, if you're in a browser and you're expecting `b` to be a global, you can use the fact that globals are attached to the `window` object and that missing object properties don't create ReferenceErrors like this:

```
console.log(window.b);   // undefined
```

Comment: "I can see some reasons for it to be this way" what do you think they are? I'd like to know to understand the internals better

Comment: @wheee - the consequences of accidentally referring to variables that are not defined when you didn't mean to can be pretty messy or confusing in downstream code.  It seems a reasonable line in the sand to draw and say that this is likely an unintended thing and should throw an error, especially since there are ways to work-around it if you're actually purposely dealing with a possibly undefined variable.  Yes, JS does let you shoot yourself in the foot other ways, but a line does have to be drawn somewhere and they decided to draw one line here.

Answer (score 5):

Because object properties are not variables. The rules are different. Accessing an object property that doesn't exist gives you `undefined`, not an error. It's just the way the language is designed.

One possible *explanation* for the difference, other than just that "that's how Eich designed it," is that you don't **declare** object properties. You just use them. But variables must be declared (other than [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and we don't have that now we have strict mode).