# When is it okay/appropriate to use logical assignment in javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, variable-assignment, logical-operators, assignment-operator

I used logical assignments like `b = a || []` in Javascript before, and there are many questions on SO about it.
To mention some:

- [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)
- [JavaScript variable assignment with OR vs if check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434161/javascript-variable-assignment-with-or-vs-if-check)
- [How does javascript logical assignment work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446433/how-does-javascript-logical-assignment-work)

And from what I read, `b = a || []` is legit code.

However, I noticed in a recent case (checking for a variable set by another script), that this code does not work as I expected.
I assumed the code would check whether `a` is falsy, and if so `[]` would be assigned to `b`. Since `undefined` is falsy, I excepted the code to work and assign `[]` in the case when `a` was not defined.

But this code causes an error:

```js
let b;

b = a || [];
console.log(b);

a = ["1", "2", "3"];
b = a || [];
console.log(b);
```

wheras

```js
let b;

b = typeof a == "undefined" ? [] : b;
console.log(b);

a = ["1", "2", "3"];
b = a || [];
console.log(b);
```

does not.
And why is it causing an error, when the error says *Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined*, which implies `a` is `undefined`?

**When can I use the logical assignment? Only when it is guaranteed that the variable (`a`) is at least declared?**

Comment: Reading an undeclared variable is always an error. It's not falsy. I'd suggest you never work with variables that are undeclared.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's not up to you, that's why I check for it.

Comment: But why does then `b = typeof a == "undefined" ? [] : b;` not cause an error?

Comment: Since JavaScript now has null coalescence operator `??`, in practice it's much safer than using `||` for a "fallback" behavior since we'll have to read a type conversion chart to ensure the behavior is what we expect.

Comment: No, it's *always* up to you. There is no real option to have a "possibly undeclared" unless you're sloppy or just don't want to write proper code.

Comment: @DanielCheung reading an undeclared variable still causes an error.

Comment: @VLAZ You are right. Though I was going to mention my comment wasn't relating to the understanding part of the problem but just the title of the question.

Comment: [Why does accessing a non-existent object property result in `undefined` instead of throwing a `ReferenceError`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31901994) | [var vs this in Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4946625) | [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488) | [How to check undefined in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43716263) | [How to check if a variable is undefined versus it is undeclared in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64406377)

Comment: @VLAZ I don't think any of those explain why `b = typeof a == "undefined" ? [] : b` does not cause an error?

Comment: [typeof !== "undefined" vs. != null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2703102) | [variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4725603) | [How can I check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3390396) | [How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/858181)

Comment: Thank you, this is basically the answer I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703122/1786528

Comment: Even so I agree with you in principle that it should be avoid, I still disagree that it is *always* up to you. When you are not the only developer or/and there is an existing code base you cannot change, you sometimes need to make sure a variable is declared/defined. That is what I was looking for.